# Karma fails with: Store.prototype.__proto__ = EventEmitter.prototype;

Tags: karma-jasmine

I'm running some javascript unit tests that use karma, and am getting the following failure

```
[exec] Store.prototype.__proto__ = EventEmitter.prototype;
```

What's causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me, I just had to upgrade to a newer version of karma, which I did by updating my dev dependencies in `package.json`

```
diff --git a/package.json b/package.json
-    "karma": "^0.12.37",
+    "karma": "^0.13.22",
```